# Coinbase delay payment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I would like to accept payments in Bitcoin through Coinbase but I would like the charge to happen only after a certain period of time. In fact, the website I manage offers car-washings that, due to weather, can be cancelled at any time; instead of issuing expensive refunds, I have opted for charging customers only once the washing has been performed.

The website is built upon Laravel 5.1 and for Bitcoin payments I would like to use Coinbase as its APIs are very well documented.

Do you know if it is possible to delay payments with Coinbase PHP APIs?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct support for this unfortunately, though it's not hard to issue refunds via the API for orders not completed.